# What to expect when the Verifier is wrong

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

Let me explain my scenario first. I'm using Scribe to connect via Oauth to an API not directly supported by Scribe. That said, the server I'm connecting to requires to enter a 4 digit number as the final step for being able to create the accessToken.

While this is working great, when the user inputs the 4 digits wrong, the app stays running forever, no error or excepction is thrown (to my understanding). This is the code I'm using:

```
//verifierString has the 4-digit number
verifier = new Verifier(verifierString);
Logger.debug("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
```

App stays in getAccessToken forever. I wonder if there is a way to control this, since it's very possible that users input the 4 digit wrong. I've checked the code for getAccessToken, Oauth 1.0 since it's the one I'm using:

```
public Token getAccessToken(Token requestToken, Verifier verifier)
{
    config.log("obtaining access token from " + api.getAccessTokenEndpoint());
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(api.getAccessTokenVerb(), api.getAccessTokenEndpoint());
    request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.TOKEN, requestToken.getToken());
    request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.VERIFIER, verifier.getValue());
    config.log("setting token to: " + requestToken + " and verifier to: " + verifier);
    addOAuthParams(request, requestToken);
    appendSignature(request);
    Response response = request.send();
    return api.getAccessTokenExtractor().extract(response.getBody());
}
```

It only seems that send() throws a RuntimeException, but not sure if catching it from my code is the right way to do it....any suggestions?

Thanks !
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try any of the `scribe` examples you'll see that entering a wrong verifier code results in an immediate `OAuthException` (note that it is an `OAuthException` though, as you correctly state it inherits from `RuntimeException`, this is by design since I'm 100% against checked exceptions).

The problem is on the server side, for what you say it keeps the http connection open for long or possibly even forever, until the default connection timeout happens.

Perhaps if you ask in the Api forums you'll get a better response, also using scribe's **debug** mode (new since 1.3.0) helps you diagnose most problems.

Comment: Thanks Pablo, that's good to know, and yeah, I think problem is at the server side. I'll have to check it out though...Thanks again!